# Download file in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, download

I create a application in which draw details on a chart by using JSON. and then save that chart as png/pdf. For this my code is -

```
function ExportPdfAndSaveChart(id, title, type, downLoadFile, selectedProject) {
        var dateForFileName = getfileDateForName();
        downLoadFile = downLoadFile + "_" + dateForFileName;
        //code to convert image from svg to canvas
        var html = d3.select(id).select("svg")
            .attr("version", 1.1)
            .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
            .node().parentNode.innerHTML;

        var imgsrc = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(html);
        var img = '<img src="' + imgsrc + '">';
        d3.select("#svgdataurl").html(img);
        var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
        iDiv.id = 'block';
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(iDiv);
        var innerDiv = document.createElement('canvas');
        iDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);
        var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
            context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        canvas.width = 800;
        canvas.height = 1130;
        context.font = "30px Arial";
        context.textAlign = 'center';
        context.fillStyle = '#fff';
        context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        var image = new Image();
        image.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
        image.src = imgsrc;
        image.onload = function () {
            context.drawImage(image, 100, 200);
            context.fillStyle = "Black";
            context.rect(10, 10, 772, 1100);
            context.stroke();
            context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
            context.lineWidth = 5;
            context.fillText(title, 380, 50);
            context.font = "20px Arial";
            context.textAlign = 'center';
            context.fillText(selectedProject, 380, 80);
            var canvasdata = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");/*"image/png", 1, 0*/
            //type=1 is for export pdf else for png
            if (type == 1) {
                pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', [297, 210]);
                pdf.setFontSize(40);
                pdf.addImage(canvasdata, 'png', 0, 0);
                pdf.save(downLoadFile + ".pdf");
            } else {
                var pngimg = '<img src="' + canvasdata + '">';
                d3.select("#pngdataurl").html(pngimg);
                var a = document.createElement("a");
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.download = downLoadFile + ".png";
                a.href = canvasdata;
                a.click();
            }
        };
    }
```

THis code is run perfectly with chrome/firefox. But in IE gives error on line - var canvasdata = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); Error is **SecurityError**

For this I set image.crossOrigin = "Anonymous"; also. But still it is not work.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled with a similar issue (with PDF files, in my case), and solved it like this:

```
$http.get('/webclientes/api/policies/getPlanFile/OLAS&&CG247S2501.pdf', {

    $http.get('/webclientes/api/policies/getPlanFile/'+datos, {
    responseType: 'blob'
    })
    .success(function(data, response) {

        vm.errorNoExistePDF = true;
        var file = new Blob([data], {
        type: 'application/pdf'
        });
        var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

        if ($window.navigator && $window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {

            $window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file);
        }else

            $window.open(fileURL);
        })
    .error (function(data){
        console.log("ERROR");
        vm.errorNoExistePDF = true;
    });
});
```

Pay attention to this bit:

```
if ($window.navigator && $window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {

            $window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file);
```