# Java Creating pie chart and download it

Tags: java, download, pie-chart

I am creating a application in which I draw pie chart in js by d3 chart from json data. And download it in pdf/png. This is work fine in chrome/firefox but not in IE.For this post question -   [Download file in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44588153/download-file-in-ie11)

As suggested now I try to draw that chart in my java code and after that download it in pdf/png form.

How should I do this in my java code

Comment: Can you be more specific regarding what part you are having trouble with? Is it about creating a pie chart in Java or about the whole infrastructure with servlets, etc. to make it available for the download? In the first case, using the `JFreeChart` library might be an option. It can render a chart as PNG or JPG data into an `OutputStream`.

Comment: It could be an issue because many times IE doesn't support some external plugins.